# Some /system/app disappear on app drawer! How to start an app not in drawer?

Tags: applications, system

Android 4.1.2

Somehow the original Home launcher icon disappeared after OTA update, I'm not sure if it's the only app that disappears, but it's the most obvious when I'm testing other launchers.

It's registered as a launcher app, so if I unset the default launcher, I can choose it.  But I'm not able to call it in App Drawer, or shortcut->application.

I wonder if wiping the dalvik cache helps?

Anyway, I'm looking for work around like running a shell script to start the app or switch to it!

Is there a file which contains the list of apps for App Drawer?

Answer (score 1):

If you replaced the stock launcher with a 3rd-party launcher, the only way to go back to stock launcher is to clear/unset the default launcher (which is what you did), and select a new launcher - in this case, the stock launcher. You will never find a shortcut to the stock launcher in your list of apps.

Comment: Yes, I can find stock launcher on app drawer before.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Apex Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher), you can browse available apps and their activities:

1. Long-tap on a free space on your homescreen
2. Select *Shortcuts*, then *Activities*
3. Scroll the list to find your "lost launcher"
4. View its activities.

There should be one activity highlighted in a different color, that's the main activity opened when you launch an app. Selecting that creates a shortcut on your homescreen you can start it from.

Writing down the activities technical name, you can also use the "app manager" from the [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line) (terminal or ADB) to launch that activity:

```
am start -n com.app.launcher/com.app.launcher.Activity
```

Here you have to replace `com.app.launcher` with the package name of the launcher/app in question, and `com.app.launcher.Activity` with what you've found out above to be the Activity's name.

Comment: Weird rules, can't edit after 5 mins.<br/>Anyway, Activity Shortcut alone can load the app, at least that works on my case.  But with ADW launcher, activities info comes with the display app name, not full name.<br/>I also tried load app action with Tasker, that works well too.

Comment: As I wrote, *Apex* shows the full activity name. You could simply install its free version to figure out, and uninstall it afterwards when no longer needed.